# ViewAttached event is not fired

Tags: javascript, dom-events, single-page-application, durandal

I'm using durandal master details sample which is using composition.I have a view model with some events defined in it,

```
 var ctor = function(name, description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    };
   

    ctor.prototype.activate = function() {
        system.log('Model Activating', this);
    };

   

    ctor.prototype.deactivate = function () {
        system.log('Model Deactivating', this);
    };

    ctor.prototype.viewAttached = function (view) {
      system.log('this is not called !', this);
    };
```

All the events except the `viewAttached` are fired. I can't find the reason here ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I was using the latest version of the Durandal fro the GithHub repository.After looking it to the composition module found that they have renamed it to `compositionComplete`. This works as expected..

```
 ctor.prototype.compositionComplete= function (view) {
      system.log('works!', this);
    };
```

**Edit**
After getting Durandal 2.0 released , in documentation we have the `attached` event instead of `viewAttached`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Durandal 2.0, the 'viewAttached' method was renamed to 'attached'.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, the only thing I can suggest checking is this note [from the Durandal docs:](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Composition/)

> Note: If you have set cacheViews:true then viewAttached will only be called the first time the view is shown, on the initial bind, since technically the view is only attached once. If you wish to override this behavior, then set alwaysAttachView:true on your composition binding.

Try setting `alwaysAttachView:true` in your binding, see if that works.

Comment: Thanks ! Found the issue.. I was using the latest version from the GitHUb repository.